# Сжатие на основе сравнения

Tags: python, сжатие

Вводится m различных сообщений произвольной длины, последовательности начальных символов в которых могут совпадать. Если такое совпадение имеется в двух сообщениях, следующих друг за другом, то начальные символы  второго сообщения заменяются программой на эквивалентное представление вида *(k), где k – количество совпадающих символов.

Я написал такой код на python:

```
#m = int(input("Введите число сообщений      "))
#arr = [[""]] * m
st = input()
arr = st.split(" ")
m = len(arr)
#for i in range(m):
#    arr[i] = input("Введите сообщение №" + str(i+1) + "       ")
k = 1;
flag = False;
def checker(k):
    count = 0;
    st1 = ""
    st2 = ""
    ml = min(len(arr[k]),len(arr[k-1]))
    for i in range(ml):
        if arr[k][i] == arr[k-1][i]:
            count += 1
            st1 += arr[k-1][i]
            if i == ml - 1:
                st2 = ("*(" + str(count) + ")")
                arr[k] = arr[k].replace(st1, st2 )
                arr[k-1] = arr[k-1].replace(st1, st2)
                count = 0
                flag = True
        else:
            if count != 0:
                st2 = ("*(" + str(count) + ")")
                arr[k] = arr[k].replace(st1, st2)
                arr[k-1] = arr[k-1].replace(st1, st2)
                flag = True
            break
    return(arr[k])
while k != m:
    if flag == False:
        arr[k] = checker(k)
        if flag == True:
            k +=2
        else:
            k +=1
    else:
        k+=1
        flag == False
for i in range(m):
    if arr[i].find("*") == 0:
        print(arr[i], end = " ")
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при выводе в первом слове символы тоже заменяются. А надо, чтоюы не заменялись. Так же если с придыдущим словом и последующим совподений нет вообще, то следующее слово не должно изменяться. Надеюсь смог объяснить, но если нет то:

При вводе:

```
Alexeev Alexandrov Alexanin Alexeenko Borkov Boris
```

в результате выполнения моей программы получаю:

```
*(4)eev *(4)androv *(4)anin *(4)eenko *(3)kov *(3)is
```

А надо чтобы было:

```
Alexeev *(4)androv *(4)anin *(4)eenko Borkov *(3)is
```

Comment: Код очень путаный, сложно разобраться. Но в целом - не нужно никаких реплейсов, делайте новый список и новые слова из старых. Так код будет и понятнее и работать должен правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы начинаете путаться в алгоритме, разбейте решение на подзадачи. я бы сделал так:

1. Сначала бы нашел количество совпадающих символов для каждой последовательной пары:

```
words = ["Alexeev", "Alexandrov", "Alexanin", "Alexeenko", "Borkov", "Boris"]
common = []

for x in range(1, len(words)):
    for y in range(len(words[x])):
        if words[x][y] != words[x-1][y]:
            break
    common.append(y)
```

а затем уже получил итоговый список:

```
result = [words[0]]
for y in words[1:]:
    s = common.pop(0)
    if s:
         y = f"*({s}){y[s:]}"
    result.append(y)

print(result)
```

> ['Alexeev', '*(4)androv', '*(6)in', '*(4)eenko', 'Borkov', '*(3)is']

Comment: Насколько я понял, ответ должен быть таким ['Alexeev', '(4)androv', '(6)in', '(4)eenko', 'Borkov', '(3)is']

Comment: @vadimvaduxa справедливо. это я перемудрил с индексами. поправил.

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ["Alexeev", "Alexandrov", "Alexanin", "Alexeenko", "Borkov", "Boris"]
result = [words[0]]
for w1, w2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
    n = sum(1 for s1, s2 in zip(w1, w2) if s1 == s2)
    result.append(w2.replace(w1[:n], f'*({n})', 1) if n else w2)
print(result)  # ['Alexeev', '*(4)androv', '*(6)in', '*(4)eenko', 'Borkov', '*(3)is']
```

Непонятно почему в 3 слове должно быть '*(4)anin', а не '(6)in', ведь во 2 слове общая часть 'Alexan', но если хочется не прерывать общую часть, если она уже была найдена ранее, то есть как у вас, продолжать брать общую часть из первого слова, то можно так:

```
words = ["Alexeev", "Alexandrov", "Alexanin", "Alexeenko", "Borkov", "Boris"]
result = [words[0]]
n = 0
for w1, w2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
    if not (n and w2.startswith(w1[:n])):
        n = sum(1 for s1, s2 in zip(w1, w2) if s1 == s2)
    result.append(w2.replace(w1[:n], f'*({n})', 1) if n else w2)
print(result)  # ['Alexeev', '*(4)androv', '*(4)anin', '*(4)eenko', 'Borkov', '*(3)is']
```

Comment: Во, с `zip`-ом я больше люблю, такой код мне кажется понятнее